# String HTML with TAG to DOCX

Tags: python, html, docx

is it possible to read an html string such as `<i><b>HelloWorld</b></i>` and print a string on word ***HelloWorld*** that is actually italic and bold?
let me explain better I have to believe a docx file from an html page and I'm using a textarea editor that returns the string formatted with the html tags I should find the way to convert them to a word readable format.
for now i'm using the python docx library

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the python docx library, but bold and italic are "run" (`<w:r>`) attributes. They're maybe the easiest to change, because they are defined inline. In your xml file, you will need something like

```
<w:r w:rsidRPr="000E1B98">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:b/>
        <w:i/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>
        HelloWorld
    </w:t>
</w:r>
```

You can see your bold `<w:b/>` and italic `<w:i/>` in that run element.

There should be a converter out there somewhere. No need to start from scratch unless you're doing something really unusual.

Comment: I would not say it is unusual I have a textarea editor that gives me the string formatted with html tags and instead I have to convert it so that it is readable by word
bold and italic were examples and I was hoping to avoid translating all the cases I thought there was something already ready some library to use